# What is the best type of door/barrier for a 96" H x 48" W uncased opening?

Tags: doors, interior

We have an uncased opening measuring 96" H x 48" W which opens to a room we would like to convert to a home office. What kind of door or other barrier would best serve this space?

We're planning on engaging with a contractor for the work but are still exploring feasibility. I'm concerned about negatively affecting home value by taking a more open plan, adding a doorway and converting it to a new room.

We've thought about something like narrow double doors which open inward that could be removed by a future homeowner if they want to leave the doorway open. Would the depth of the wall affect the feasibility of this option? We've also thought about a higher quality accordion door which could be added without too much modification to the opening. Being a home office reducing noise would be a huge benefit.

Pocket doors aren't an option due to the angled wall. Barn doors would be cool but I can't find anything about mounting them where they slide on an angle like this. One 48" door would probably be too big as it would eat up a lot of interior space with the door sweep. We think that changing this to be a regular doorway would look funny and inhibit the open concept for future owners too.

See pictures:
[image: Opening (Interior View)]
[image: Opening (Exterior View)]

Comment: Temporarily? Permanently? What are your priorities? "Best" is a meaningless word here.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Easy reversibility, awkward walls and sound deadening lead me to suggest heavy (probably multi-layered or quilted) drapes/curtains. Do be sure the material is fire-treated (or else fire treat it yourself) since that is one easily preventable issue with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I had an opening similar to this going into a narrow laundry area. It was 72" wide so I used two 36" accordion doors. You could utilize two 24" doors, one mounted on each side. They have 4 clips mounted on the side and three screws for the track on top. They would be very easy to remove if/when needed. When opened, they take up about 5" on each side.

Comment: Accordion doors are what came to mind for me, too. They can be mounted and removed with only minor drywall repair. They're also probably less expensive than other options.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a guess that you're going to convert the carpeted space into the office:

I'd suggest glass French doors that open *into* the carpeted space. French doors open in the middle, so each door would be a bit less than 24" wide and take up minimal wall and floor space to open. They would, of course, still cut off a sliver of that angle of the wall, but the space lost behind them would be minimal.

When closed, they're glass so the space still appears "open". This also allows you to close the door to indicate to the kids that you're working, but allows you to keep an eye on what's happening in the tiled space (assuming kids that age remain stationary enough that you can see 'em ;).

When open, they'll tuck away more or less against the walls of the office, minimizing  their space usage. One door will cover the existing light switches so they'll have to be moved. Possibly put a "main" switch outside the room to turn a light on before entering (though there should be enough light from the tiled room to safely find your way to the carpeted room switch), then put the other two switches in the next-most-convenient location where they're not covered by a door.

This appears to be a corner off of an otherwise open space. As a thought, instead of glass, you could use a solid door and not lose much of the "open concept" since you're only cutting off a small corner. A solid door would *probably* be cheaper than a glass door and would also offer privacy and allow greater focus on "office stuff" when closed.